# Ошибка RecyclerView Android

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Хочу добавить полученные данные из VK в Recycler.

**Fragment**

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private final FriendAdapter mFriendAdapter = new FriendAdapter();
    VKList vkListFriends;
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public static FriendsFragment newInstance() {
        return new FriendsFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_friends_item, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name", "last_name"));
        request.executeSyncWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
//
                Log.d("Ответ от сервера", response.responseString);
                vkListFriends = (VKList)response.parsedModel;
                for (Object vkFriends: vkListFriends){
                    Friend friend = (Friend)vkFriends;
                    mFriendAdapter.addData(friend);
                }






            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                super.onError(error);
            }
        });
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFriendAdapter);

    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class FriendAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FriendHolder> {
    private List<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FriendHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_friends_item, parent, false);
        return new FriendHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FriendHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.bind(friends.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return friends.size();
    }

    void addData(Friend friend){
        friends.add(friend);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**ViewHolder**

```
public class FriendHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView tvFirstName;
    private TextView tvLastName;

    public FriendHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvFirstName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_first_name);
        tvLastName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_last_name);
    }

    public void bind(Friend friend) {
        tvLastName.setText(friend.getLast_name());
        tvFirstName.setText(friend.getFirst_name());
    }
}
```

**XML фрагменты Recycler**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**XML item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_first_name"
                android:text="first_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_last_name"
                android:text="last_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>





</LinearLayout>
```

Выкидывает ошибку, как будто LinearLayoutManager равен Null.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.vkmobileapp, PID: 5921
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.vkmobileapp/com.example.vkmobileapp.SignInActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3685)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1643)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.vkmobileapp.friend.FriendsFragment.onActivityCreated(FriendsFragment.java:78)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1483)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:391)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:517)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1354)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3620)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3685) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1643) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: странно, для создания View во фрагменте с RecyclerView и в вашем холдере для одного item, вы используете один и тот же layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть предположение, что вы методом inflate() "раздуваете" не тот layout, в вашем фрагменте.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, 
@Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundl savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_friends_item, container, 
false);
    }
```

R.layout.list_friends_item, судя по названию layout это layout элемента, а не layout где ваш RecyclerView. Из за этого вы и получаете NullPointerException при вызове метода setLayoutManager().

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на выдаваемую ошибку

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.vkmobileapp.friend.FriendsFragment.onActivityCreated(FriendsFragment.java:78)
```

(Попытка вызвать виртуальный метод setLayoutManager на нулевой ссылке)

У вас **RecyclerView (а не LayoutManager)** равен null, из-за этого проблемы. Это значит, что вот здесь во FriendsFragment...

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        //...
    }
```

... ваш RecyclerView не может найтись.

Проблема может быть в том, что вы устанавливаете разметку, в которой нет вашего RecyclerView, поэтому он и не может найтись: здесь во FriendsFragment...

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_friends_item, container, false);
    }
```

... вы устанавливаете разметку `list_friends_item.xml`. Проверьте, что **именно в этой** разметке находится RecyclerView c `android:id="@+id/recycler_view"`.

Comment: Зачем давать такой же ответ, который уже есть :)

Comment: Упс. Не увидел. Когда я начинал писать, ответов еще не было)